# how to use quote in mysql syntax?

Tags: mysql

I try this in PHPMyadmin:

```
Update wp_1_posts 
   SET post_content='<strong>Hello </strong> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a> you think you're good at sql.\n then answer\n' 
 WHERE post_ti<tle = 'stupid example'
```

and it says bad syntax. Why ?

Comment: It also helps if you post the full output of the error.  Many times MySQL will give you a more verbose error that can show you exactly where your error is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With MySQL, single-quotes inside a string have to be escaped, putting a `\` before them :

```
'this is a string with a \' quote inside of it'
```

As a reference, you can take a look to this section of the MySQL manual :

- [8.1.1. Strings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-syntax.html)

In your case, your query should look like this :

```
Update wp_1_posts 
SET post_content='<strong>Hello </strong> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a> you think you\'re good at sql.\n then answer\n' 
WHERE post_title = 'stupid example'
```

Note the `\` I've added in `think you\'re good`.

Answer (score 3):

You can see it in your post. The red text ends at the ' in you're. You need to escape the quote. You can simply add \ before it. you\'re.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the single quote in the word `you're` to make it `you\'re` in your statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape quotes inside string (read the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html)).

```
Update wp_1_posts SET post_content='<strong>Hello </strong> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a> you think you\'re good at sql.\n then answer\n' WHERE post_title = 'stupid example'
```